# Need help in creating a section for each product as new attribute section

Tags: module, magento-1.8

I am trying to create a new attribute section as `Q & A` for each "*configurable product*". This Section will have a table which will have the following columns:

- Question ID
- Created On
- Question
- Answer
- Product ID -- current product's ID
- Status

---

If you can't understand what I actually meant by section:

- In `admin -> Catalog -> manage products -> select any configurable product`

[image]

For this purpose, I am using **[Online Module Creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)**. Using this generator, I filled the fields which I could have understand. Here is the **[PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0hddygxq5jsr0k/Magento%20Module%20Creator%20_%20SilkSoftware.pdf)** which explains which fields I had added. After creating the module, I downloaded it and merged the files in my project folder.

The problem is that I can't see the created table which is `catalog_product_queries` in the database and also I can't see the `Q & A` section anywhere in the admin panel.

One thing I realized, In the Module creator, I haven't mentioned that where I am adding this table to.

You can download the generated module from **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5yem08vm7ue1gp/Efk_Queries.zip)**.

Comment: Marius is fairly active on here and is the author of the Module Creator: http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator.html) (or [from github](https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator) if you prefer that).
It should do what you need.
The extension will create the files needed to manage your own entities. You can even link those entities to the products. If you choose this option, a new tab will be created on the product add/edit page where you can select the entity instances to be associated to a certain product.
It also works the other way around. In your entity add/edit screen you can select the products to be associated to that entity.
It will also generate the files needed to show your entities on the product view page. Some css and markup changes may be required to make it fit in your theme.